# How can I convert a VMWare Fusion 3 .vmdk to .raw format?

Tags: vmware-fusion

I’ve got a VMWare virtual machine that I want to upload to a virtual server hosting service. The service accepts virtual machine images in .raw format (as per “How Can I Migrate VMWare Virtual Servers into Your Cloud” on http://www.serverlove.com/cloud-server-faqs/uploading-server-images-and-cds/).

How can I convert my virtual machine’s virtual hard disk into .raw format? The virtual machine is running Debian 6.

My host OS is Mac OS X 10.6, and I couldn’t work out how to compile Qemu on it (`./configure; make;` returned an error.)

I was wondering if one of the command-line tools at `/Library/Application Support/VMWare Fusion/` might do it? E.g. `vmware-rawdiskCreator`?

Comment: One way would be mounting the drive and copying it as a block device to a file with the `dd` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMWare provide a guide for this, for Windows guests:

http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/

If your guest OS is Linux, VirtualBox may be able to convert it.

Comment: Ah yes — that looks spot on; unfortunately it requires the virtual machine to be running Windows. Mine’s running Debian Linux (sorry, I failed to mention that on the original question).

Comment: Then you may be able to achieve it by installing VirtualBox and using the `VBoxManage` command.

Comment: aha, cheers, I’ll give that a go.

Comment: VirtualBox worked a treat, many thanks for the tip.

Comment: Specifically: `VBoxManage clonehd PATH_TO_VMDK_FILE PATH_FOR_RAW_VERSION --format RAW`. The VMDK file lives inside the the virtual machine’s bundle (in the Terminal it’s the bundle’s name in the Finder plus `.vmwarevm`), and you can find its file name in the GUI by selecting the VM, and selecting Virtual Machine > Settings > Removable Devices > Hard Disk.