# How can I run a virtual machine from a RAW format disk image on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a Debian Linux web server running in VMWare on my laptop. I use a VPS hosting company that lets me upload a copy of this virtual machine’s disk image to use as a live web server, meaning I’ve got an exact copy of my web server on my laptop for testing before deployment.

The hosting company requires the image to be uploaded in RAW format, so [I’ve used VirtualBox to convert the VMWare .vmdk image file into RAW format](https://superuser.com/questions/262472/how-can-i-convert-a-vmware-fusion-3-vmdk-to-raw-format) before uploading.

Having recently re-uploaded the image, it’s not working once uploaded. I’ll be querying this with the hosting company’s support after Christmas to see if they can figure out what I’ve done wrong, but I wanted to run the RAW copy of the disk image locally, to see if I messed something up during conversion.

What software can I use on OS X Lion to run a virtual machine on the RAW disk image? Neither VMWare nor VirtualBox seem to support creating a virtual machine that uses the RAW format disk image as its disk.